# Javascript element handling

Tags: javascript, function, object, dom

I've made a table with many griditems which come from a database. 
I'm using pure Javscript and AJAX for editing and deleting those griditems.

**Code:**

```
var main_table=document.getElementById('main-table'),//get the element handler for the table
griditems=main_table.querySelectorAll('.griditem'),//get an array with all the griditems in the main-table
griditems_count=griditems.length;
var griditem_array = [];

for(var i=0;i<griditems_count;i++){
    griditem_array[i] = new create_griditem(griditems, i); //here i create a array for every single element and pass the handler for the griditems and the position on the table to the object

function create_griditem(griditems, griditems_count){
    var pos=griditems_count;
    var id=griditems[pos].getAttribute('data-id'); //the griditem div's also have the id from the Database

    var griditems_buttons=griditems[pos].querySelectorAll('.griditem-buttons');
    var del_button = griditems_buttons[0].querySelectorAll('.delete')[0];
    del_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('Delete '+id);
    }, false);

    //there are more things called for creating a delete and edit button for every griditem
}
```

I'm getting every griditem from the table and create an object array for every single griditem for creating the appropriate buttons for the corresponding item.

my problem is, as you can see on line 13(*griditems[pos]*), I'm getting the element handle(or DOM handle) through the position in the query selector from the main table. 
**BUT** this grid is a sortable grid, so I can drag and drop the items and the position for the griditem with the corresponding id is somewhere completely different.

So how do I get DOM handler through my id, which I'm passing to the object?
Or can someone give my advice how to code the whole situation in a better way?

**Edit:**

I've created a fiddle the see the whole thing running: http://jsfiddle.net/MCRte/

As you can see,in the last line `main_table.removeChild(griditems[pos]);`, I'm getting the DOM handle through the position in the query selector(.griditem) for the main-table. But what if the sorting of those changed before i deleted one... any other would be deleted.

How to i get the DOM handle through the id?

Comment: The following line doesn't make sense
     `griditem_array[i] = new create_griditem(griditems, i);`
You should not be calling `new` on something that is not a constructor. What does `create_griditem` return?

Comment: `create_griditem` doesn't return anything on it's own. I'm just creating inherited functions that return something. Like `this.getID=function(){return id;}` cause id is a private Variable

Comment: If you don't follow JS conventions, everyone will have a hard time following your code. Constructors should be `FirstLetterUpperCase` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style and https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml Also, it's very hard to tell what the problem is... Complicated problems require code that we can run, steps to reproduce, actual results and expected results as bullet items. Long paragraphs are difficult to follow. Please improve the question (if you want someone to help you)

Comment: One more thing, it seems like you mean "handle" but you are saying "handler" instead. Please be more careful with the language you use. A "handler" is a function that is called when something happens, a "handle" is a pointer to an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use an auto executing anonymous function at all. Just use the browser event API.

The event handler function receives a single argument called `event` which is the click event object. The `event.target` property is the element that was clicked by the user, which in your case would be the button that has the class name ".delete". You can climb the document tree from that element until you reach an element that has the ".griditem" class name, and grab the `data-id` attribute in order to know which element to delete.

```
var gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('#main-table .griditem'),
    i = 0,
    length = gridItems.length;

for(i; i < length; i++) {
    gridItems[i]
        .querySelector(".griditem-buttons .delete")
        .addEventListener("click", deleteGridItem);
}

function deleteGridItem(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var gridItem = event.target;

    // Climb the document tree from the .delete button to the .griditem
    while (gridItem) {
        if (gridItem.classList.contains("griditem")) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            gridItem = gridItem.parentNode;
        }
    }

    if (gridItem) {
        alert("Delete item: " + gridItem.getAttribute("data-id"));
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Failed to find griditem");
    }
}
```

I'm assuming at some point the table row will be removed from the document. You must detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks. I've found the best way to do this is by utilizing Event Delegation.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yj2eg/

```
var table = document.getElementById("main-table");

table.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("BUTTON");

        if (event.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
            deleteItem(event.target);
        }
        else if (event.target.classList.contains("edit")) {
            editItem(event.target);
        }
    }
});

function deleteItem(button) {
    var gridItem = getGridItem(button);

    if (confirm("Delete item: " + gridItem.getAttribute("data-id") + "?")) {
        gridItem.parentNode.removeChild(gridItem);
    }
}

function editItem(button) {
    var gridItem = getGridItem(button);

    alert("Edit item: " + gridItem.getAttribute("data-id"));
}

function getGridItem(button) {
    var gridItem = button;

    while (gridItem) {
        if (gridItem.classList.contains("griditem")) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            gridItem = gridItem.parentNode;
        }
    }

    if (!gridItem) {
        throw new Error("Could not find griditem");
    }

    return gridItem;
}
```

Comment: Sry for the late answer. But WOW! Thank you! It was exactly the answer i was looking for! It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely certain what your actual problem is, but if you're trying to set up a click listener for a button within one of your griditems that performs an action based on the griditem's data-id attribute, something like this would do the job:

```
var main_table = document.getElementById('main-table');   //get the element handler for the table
var griditems = main_table.querySelectorAll('.griditem'); //get an array with all the griditems in the main-table

for (var i = 0; i < griditems.length; i++) {
    var griditem = griditems[i];
    var id = griditem.getAttribute('data-id');
    var del_button = griditem.querySelector('.delete');
    del_button.addEventListener('click', function(id) {
        alert('Delete ' + id);
    }(id), false);
}
```